# what happens if a Telnet adds more data during a busy thread handling previous Telnet data

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I have a program that starts a Telnet background thread, which listens data that is put on network at random time by one or more different equipments. Interval between events may start from a few seconds to several minutes, which is more than enough for the thread to handle the incoming data.

However, there is a chance that two equipments put data at almost the same time. Alternatively, a combination of [slow thread processing due to modest hardware and complex code] + [very quick data put successively by one single fast equipment] might be expected.

Question: what happens with a second data sequence that happens to be put on network right after a first sequence, in case my thread is still busy handling the first one?
The data is lost? (from the thread perspective)
Or, is there some signaling & queue mechanism so the Telnet client/thread will find what happened during its short absence?

The program runs on a Raspberry Pi. Here is the thread init and the main part of the thread, if that helps understanding:

```
# executed earlier in program
qq = queue.Queue()
th = threading.Thread(target = ReadFromBMDThread, args = (qq,self.tn))
th.start()
# ...
```

```
# thread
class ReadFromBMDThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, qq, tn):
        global INCOMING
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        threading_flag = True
        while threading_flag:
            try:
                data = tn.read_until(b"\n\n")
            except Exception as e:
                LOG.WriteLog(self, ("ReadFromBMDThread:  " + str(e)))
            INCOMING = (data.decode())
            # ...
            # some more program which increases processing time
```

Resulted INCOMING are data blocks of single pairs in the form of number-space-number, each pair on one line, each line ended by \n and each data block ended by \n\n (which are then striped by `decode()`).
Example of INCOMING data:

4 20

115 77
23 6

...

**Edit:** I applied Elliott Frisch's idea – the result: it seems the queue is preserved. I added a `time.sleep(5)` at the end of thread sequence and the whole data that was put on network during the waiting interval was still well handled, one data block after each and every 5 seconds, without overlap and without data loss.

:)

Comment: What happened when you tried it locally? TELNET twice in seperate commands to the local port you're listening on.

Comment: **Edit:** see the 'Edit:' on main question. (This is what I commented here previously: Normally it is unlikely I can hit that fast different Telnet commands, but the idea is a good one: I can insert an artificial pause in my thread just for testing purpose. Yes, I will try, thank you :) (will put later the result here, if relevant))